# JQuery - making variables with the $(this) selector global?

Tags: jquery, variables, css-selectors, global

I have two buttons, when clicked they each call a different function. Both functions share the same variables. How would I go about making these variables global so they can be set by each function? Example:

```
$('#button_one').bind('click', functionOne);
$('#button_two').bind('click', functionTwo);

function functionOne(){
   var exOne = $(this).attr('id');
   var exTwo = $(this).text();

   // do stuff here
};

function functionTwo(){
   var exOne = $(this).attr('id');
   var exTwo = $(this).text();

   // do stuff here
};
```

How would one achieve something like this?

```
$('#button_one').bind('click', functionOne);
$('#button_two').bind('click', functionTwo);

exOne = $(this).attr('id');
exTwo = $(this).text();    

function functionOne(){
   // do stuff here
};

function functionTwo(){
   // do stuff here
};
```

Thanks for the input!!!

Comment: Those variables aren't the same - they'll contain different values for each button.

Answer (score 2):

Declare them as global :)

```
$('#button_one').bind('click', functionOne);
$('#button_two').bind('click', functionTwo);

var exOne;
var exTwo;

function functionOne(){
   exOne = $(this).attr('id');
   exTwo = $(this).text();

   // do stuff here
};

function functionTwo(){
   exOne = $(this).attr('id');
   exTwo = $(this).text();

   // do stuff here
};
```